# Admob Limit Placed on my Account More Than 8 months

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Ad serving on your account is currently being limited due to invalid traffic concerns. We’ll automatically review and update this limit as we continue to monitor your traffic.
It's been 8 months now the limit is still there and of course, there is no way to contact the AdMob team. It all started when I ran a google ads install campaign for one of my apps and I got a very high volume of installs and thus high impression and earnings from the app, then boom I got a limit on my account. I have paused the campaign and deleted all the ad unit id for all my apps and after 7 days the warning goes away but when I create a new ad unit and I get as little as 10 requests and 2 impressions the limit comes back. I have done that several times but it's Limit still comes and goes. I don't know what to do anymore please I need your help. Below is how I show Admob ads via firebase in my app.

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
//innitiatizing the ads
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1137773547201239/7187777199");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());//loading the ads
        
         if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

            final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
            dialog.show();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);

        }
         mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());//Reloading the ads
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the code and permissions in my manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-1132553547777239~2704777871"/>
```

Comment: Any solutions, I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: I also did a install campaign, and then a week after that my ad servings is limited. Have you found any solution yet?